# Why is sed deleting my header row?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using sed to replace the second comma on every line of file.txt with a dash (-) :

```
this,is_the,header_row
a,1,2
b,1,2
c,1,2

while read line; do
    sed 's/,/-/2' > file_new.txt
done < file.txt
```

Expected output:

```
this,is_the-header_row
a,1-2
b,1-2
c,1-2
```

What I get:

```
a,1-2
b,1-2
c,1-2
```

Why is sed deleting my header row?

( Apologies if this is a duplicate question. Searches for variations of
"sed deleting first row" only return variations of "how to delete first row")

GNU bash, version 4.3.27(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)

Comment: The answer from hek2mgl below is most correct; here's a bonus: if you want to come in from a stream (e.g. via `cat`), you could do: `cat file.txt | sed 's/,/-/2' > file_new.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, without the while loop:

```
sed 's/,/-/2' file.txt > file_new.txt
```

Output:

```
this,is_the-header_row
a,1-2
b,1-2
c,1-2
```

`sed` will iterate over the file on it's own and applies the command to every line.

Answer (score 1):

hek2mgl has the correct solution to your goal but the answer to your question is a bit more complicated.

At first I was going to say that that loop should only get you the last line of the input file in the output file but then I tested it and it didn't.

Turns out I missed something that you missed too.

You aren't giving `$line` to `sed` there. You aren't giving it anything. It is reading from standard input.

You've opened stdin from `file.txt` for that while loop but sed inherits that. So the read eats line 1 and sed snarfs up the rest of the lines from the file, spits them to stdout (which goes to the output file) and your while loop then terminates when `read` sees `EOF`.

If you were feeding `$line` to `sed` in that loop you would get the behaviour I initially thought which is only the last line in the file (since you are using `>` and not `>>`).

Comment: `the read eats line 1 and sed snarfs up the rest of the lines from the file` That's it! +1 Nice answer!

Comment: Excellent! This answer also helps with a couple of other nagging problems I've been having.